# What method is being used during JMS serialization?

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I am modifying an API that uses Symfony 2.7 and JMS Serializer. I have an entity that includes some image data. In my entity definition, the relevant field is annotated as follows:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="images_data", type="text")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "playlist", "digital_signage", "distributed_item"})
 * @JMS\Type("array")
 * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getImagesDataDecode")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("imagesData")
 */
private $imagesData;
```

... and I have changed the getImagesDataDecode() method to look like this:

```
public function getImagesDataDecode()
{
    return ['testone'=>'a','testtwo'=>'b'];
}
```

... but during testing, my API endpoint does not return the new test array. I can only conclude that the getImagesDataDecode() method is not being used during the API response.

**How do I find out which method is being used to return API data?**

I hope to make my program do a bit of analysis and filtering before returning the data in question. Without a place to insert that logic, it looks like I'm temporarily out of luck.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and following the track that makes the call? And put a breaking point on the getImagesDataDecode() method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried putting a breakpoint in getImagesDataDecode(), and the method is not getting called. That leaves me unsure about how to proceed.

Comment: Well, it looks like the method isn't being called. Before you modified your code, was it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `@JMS\AccessType` annotation to tell the serializer to use your Accessor method. It defaults to `property` and therefore it doesn't use any methods, it uses the property itself through a reflection.

https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accesstype